# Loop through an object and get all the values of the keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop through an object and get all the key values that is name and I am doing it in the following way :

```
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

returnName(fakeData) {
    for (key in fakeData.cars && fakeData.usedCars) {
     //return name property  of cars and usedCars arrays.
     //fakeData is the representation of the req.body data that might 
     //sometimes not necessarily have either cars or usedCars

    }

}
```

It returns undefined if I do this. Is there any way to fit those conditions in one for loop and get the desired results?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get all the key values that is name"? Do you mean you want to get a list of name values from both cars and used cars combined?

Comment: yes that is correct, so it would be CALI, TEXAS, NY, FL @sofa_maniac

Comment: attention, cars and usedCars are array, not objects

Comment: Assuming `cars` and `usedCars` are never undefined, simple `[...fakeData.cars, ...fakeData.usedCars].map(car => car.title)`

Comment: @divillysausages this would not work is either of them were missing

Comment: @boomchickawawa that's why I said "Assuming cars and usedCars are never undefined" :)

Comment: If either can be `undefined`, then just use `[...(fakeData.cars || []), ...(fakeData.usedCars || [])].map(car => car.title)`

Comment: that is actually a great answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job.

```
(fakeData.cars?fakeData.cars:[]).concat(fakeData.usedCars?fakeData.usedCars:[]).map(car => car.name)
```

Output:

```
["CALI", "TEXAS", "NY", "FL"]
```

Explanation:

First, we use a conditional to check if faekData.cars actually exists or not. If it does, get the array. If not, return an empty array in its place.

```
  (fakeData.cars)?fakeData.cars:[]
```

This translates to: (condition==true)? (do this if true):(do this if false)

If the array does not exist, the condition will not be satisfied. So, the "(do this if false)" part will be executed.

Then, we do the same with the second array. By using "concat", we concatenate both arrays into a single one. Then, we use "map" to transform the whole objects into just the value of the "name" property.

Comment: that works great. could you please explain the what is happening here? @sofa_maniac

Comment: I think the previous answer that you posted works well, because this one returns [Object object] @sofa_maniac

Comment: i.e `fakeData.cars.concat(fakeData.usedCars?fakeData.usedCars:[]).map(car => car.name);`

Comment: actually scratch that

Comment: I forgot to wrap the first part in a parenthesis.

Comment: is it possible to add spaces to the output? Tried using `join(', ')` but that didn't seem to work

Comment: This works fine: (fakeData.cars?fakeData.cars:[]).concat(fakeData.usedCars?fakeData.usedCars:[]).map(car => car.name).join(', ')

Comment: I was using it before the map my bad, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you're looking for.

```js
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
};

[].concat(
    fakeData.cars ? fakeData.cars : [],
    fakeData.usedCars ? fakeData.usedCars : [],
    fakeData.undefinedCars ? fakeData.undefinedCars : [],
).forEach(car => {
    console.log(car.name);
});
```

For more arrays just add them into the `.concat()` function separated by a comma:

`array1.concat(array2, array3, array4)`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this would not work if either usedCars array or cars array is missing and would throw an error saying `Cannot read name of undefined`. Is there any other way to make this work apart from using optional chaining?

Comment: My new edit should have achieved that for you.

Comment: Note the newest edit wasn't working until I added a semicolon `;` to the end of the `fakeData` object.

Answer (score 0):

`for (key in fakeData.cars && fakeData.usedCars)` doesn't mean "get me the keys in cars and usedCars", it means "get me the keys of the evaluation of cars && usedCars" (which is cars since it's truthy).

Instead, just use a `.map` and get the names out:

```js
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

/*
This doesn't mean "get me the keys in cars and usedCars"
it means "get me the keys of the evaluation of cars && usedCars"
(which is cars since it's truthy)
returnName(fakeData) {
    for (key in fakeData.cars && fakeData.usedCars) {
     //return name property  of cars and usedCars arrays.
     //fakeData is the representation of the req.body data that might 
     //sometimes not necessarily have either cars or usedCars

    }

}
*/

// You can just map the arrays and spread them into a new array:
// If you have to deal with certain properties not being there,
// you can use optional chaining, the ? and ?? [] pieces
const names = [
  ...fakeData?.cars?.map(({name}) => name) ?? [],
  ...fakeData?.usedCars?.map(({name}) => name) ?? []
];

console.log(names); // ["CALI", "TEXAS", "NY", "FL"]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. This does not work if the usedCars is missing in the request body. It throws an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`  @zero298

Comment: @boomchickawawa You can use optional chaining if you have to handle certain properties not being there.

Comment: Yes that makes total sense, but it is not supported by previous node versions so is there any alternative to optional chaining? @zero298

Answer (score 0):

This should print all the car names

```
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

var results = [];

function returnNames(){
    for(index in fakeData.cars){
        results.push(fakeData.cars[index].title);
    }
    for(index in fakeData.usedCars){
        results.push(fakeData.usedCars[index].title);
    }
    
    console.log("car names: " + results)
}
```

Comment: I think using two for loops would be an overkill, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could concat the objects you want into an array and map out whatever values you'd like to access. Is that what you're looking for?

```js
const fakeData = {
    manufacturer: 'tesla',
    cars: [
      { title: 'CALI', name: 'CALI', type: 'string' },
      { title: 'TEXAS', name: 'TEXAS', type: 'string' },
      { title: 'NY', name: 'NY', type: 'string' }
    ],
    usedCars: [{ title: 'FL', name: 'FL', type: 'string' }]
  };
  
  const combinedCarData = [...fakeData.cars, ...fakeData.usedCars];
  
  // Map whatever values you would like to access
  
  combinedCarData.map(car => {
    console.log(car.title);
    console.log(car.name);
    console.log(car.type);
  });
```